# Strange copy constructor for a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, doubly-linked-list

***Please note my homework tag. As with all homework, helpful suggestions over straight answers to actual coding is appreciated. Feel free to answer any of my conceptual questions straight forwardly, though.***

Hello,

My professor assigned us a doubly linked list for homework, and I was avoiding asking for help until I absolutely needed it, and here I am.

He provides us header files, which we then have to make a class for, and *must* follow the header file perfectly. The way he does his **copy constructor** is that he makes us write a helper function that we just have the copy constructor call.

I can do this easily, on a normal case, but this time he has given us a very bizarre signature for the helper function:

```
// copys chain at oldHead to newHead.
static void copy(Elem *&newHead, const Elem *oldHead)
```

This is to copy a chain of structs called Elems:

```
struct Elem 
{
    Information info;
    Elem *next;
    Elem *back;
};
```

I guess I'm mostly confused as to what the whole Elem *& business because, from what I remember, don't & and * cancel each other out?

Thanks, any and all help is really appreciated! Hopefully this will help other people in my position in the future:)

Comment: In C++ that's a *reference to a pointer*.

Comment: In an *expression*, `&` is the address-of operator, as you already know. In a *declaration*, `&` denotes a reference declaration. These unrelated concepts unfortunately share the same symbol. If you can understand that bit, then everyone else's comments about `Elem *&newHead` being a reference-to-a-pointer-to-Elem should make sense.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/references.html

Comment: Your teacher probably did a lot of C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static Elem* copy(const Elem *oldHead)
```

Could have been a potential function. You take the old Head and return the new cloned Head.

What he chose is passing the pointer by reference.

If it was simply

```
static void copy(Elem * newHead, const Elem *oldHead)
{
    newHead = new Elem();
}
```

something like above. Any changes to newHead is not visible to outside the function.

This is the same below. x is passed by value. Any changes to x are forgotten after the function **Addten** returns. Your x just happens to be a pointer.

```
   void Addten( int x )
    {
       x = x + 10;
    }

    int x = 10;
    Addten( x );
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. It's one of those things that is so well known that it's impossible to find on the internet or in a book easily.

Comment: if you like the answer , please consider upvoting it